# field_group #states does not working with using hook_field_group_build_pre_render_alter()

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use `#states` on field_group at node add form.

From the search results I can find a couple of links which shows that `hook_field_group_build_pre_render_alter()` can make the magic but there is no luck for me.

I try to clear cache and `dpm()` some message inside the function. It seems the hook function has not been implemented at all.

These are the links I found.

- [Conditional fieldgroups/fieldsets in Drupal 7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13210979/1146907)
- [hook_form_alter form state problems](https://www.drupal.org/node/1053174#comment-9153819)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gotten hook_field_group_build_pre_render_alter(&$element) to work.  Without seeing an example of your code, it's hard to give any really helpful advice.

Here's an example for a nested fieldgroup made visible when a checkbox field is checked (the checkbox boolean field is "field_primary_not_caller"):

```
function MYMODULE_field_group_build_pre_render_alter(&$element) {
    //... Detect whether this is the right form...
    $element['group_contact']['group_primary_contact']['#states'] = array(
      'visible' => array(
        '#edit-field-primary-not-caller-und' => array('checked'=>TRUE),
      ),
    );
}
```

Finally, it's truly worthwhile to invest the time in getting xDebug up and running on your development machine - much better and easier to use than dpm()/var_dump()/etc, can save you hours with stuff like this.

Comment: Yes. xDebug is better but settings up xDebug is always a  nightmare to me.

Answer (score 2):

After debugging I found that `hook_field_group_build_pre_render_alter()` is indeed working, but `dpm()` cannot work inside it at all.

For debugging, you can only use `var_dump()` or `kpr()` inside this hook function.